# Error in if (type == "xls") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm new in R and have this problem:

Error in if (type == "xls") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have this code and I don't know what the problem is:

```
   for (i in 1:length(data))
{ 
  setwd("D:\\Baltoro\\Landsat_2017\\Shape_area")
  Shape = shapefile(data[i])
  filename = file[i]

    for (ii in 1:14)
  { 
    area = shapefile(name_area[ii])
    trans = spTransform(area, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=43 +ellps=WGS84"))
    Shape1 = crop(Shape,trans)
    name = sapply(filename, FUN=function(k) paste0(k, "_", ii, ".xlsx"))

    if (is.na(Shape1))
    { 
      print(name)
     print("empty")
     }

   else
    {
    Shape1$area_sqm = area(Shape1)
    Table = Shape1$area_sqm
    setwd("D:\\Baltoro\\Auswertung\\Detail_2017")
    write.xlsx(Table, file=name[i])
    print(name)
    print("done")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually see the code `if (type == "xls")` anywhere.  Are you sure you posted the full code above?

Comment: Yes it is the full code. Because of that I don't understand the error

Comment: The error comes from `write.xlsx`. Looks like you are using the xlsx package because when it creates a workbook it does some checks with `type == "xls"`. You will have to debug the else code to see what is going on exactly. or try using the write.xlsx function from the openxlsx package. No java dependency in that one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed and loaded the library(openxlsx). Now it works :)